# Jquery animations are slow in google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, animation

I am not sure if this question is really specific for SO but I still would like to ask.

Has anyone noticed that jquery animations became less smooth on Chrome, if you just find a jquery plugin it seems very nice but usually on demo pages there is a little amount of tags and another javascript funcions. I am currently working on a project with rich interative interface using a lot of fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions (taking 300 as an argument). While in IE9, Opera and FF4 they run very smooth chrome cannot render them properly.

For instance, chrome displays in very "unsmooth" way such a simple task as display 400x100px div with fixed position using function fadeIn(300).

is it only my problem, or have you noticed something similar recently? I have tried stable and dev releases but with no luck, and as I have metioned all the other browsers can handle smooth animations.

Update: this is an example:

```
$('#ms_cal_menu').click(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $('#cal_submenu').css("top", offset.top+'px').css('left', offset.left-5+'px').fadeIn(300);        
});
```

Comment: can you post the code you're using or posting a link to ur page is more helpful

Comment: I have updates the post, this is the simpliest animation, but the problem is that chrome fails on all the animations. I also haven't found any warnings in the developer tools

Comment: @mike your code is working fine, http://jsbin.com/ipewu3 . might be something wrong with your Markup or CSS

Comment: should I try to rewrite it i from scratch because now it uses 9 jquery plugins and has 1400 lines of code? I just find it a little weird that only chrome fails to render jquery animations correctly.

Comment: I have the project on the localhost but I exported source of html, css and js files: http://snipt.org/koXk/ (html), http://snipt.org/koXl/ (css), http://snipt.org/koXn/ (js)

Comment: @mike it's too difficult for me  to search the documents you know. I'm sorry dude. I really  mean it

Comment: don't worry, thank you your response anyway :)

Comment: Have you checked Chrome's GPU acceleration?

Comment: Sometimes when is Activated it slows down the rendering in certain GPUs

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating a race condition. If you are using submenus and clicking from here to there, each time you are starting a process - and each process must have time to complete.

What happens when you want to move to another menu item? Is it the mouseout that starts a fade out? What happens if your fade in is not completed?

I know you say that "it works" in other browsers but I bet I could get it to fall over in a few seconds. You need to control behaviours that can lead to race conditions but apart from that it will be pretty annoying for your users after a while if every selection of a menu triggers a flashy animation. It's "pretty" on first viewing - but painful in everyday use.

Can't you just use a `.show()` and `.hide()` ?